# How do you do alegbra correctly in Lua?

Tags: lua

So i have recently been attempting to do alegbra in lua and this was the closet way i could come up with of doing it is this how you are even supposed to do it correctly? An other problem that i find with doing alegbra in  lua is that in alegbra there is both a constant and a variable beside eachother well the problem with that is that lua does not like both a Number and a letter beside eachother so it errors is there any way how i could go about doing alegbra inside lua without getting errors?

```
local a = 5

-- ALEGBRA?
print(((a * 2) / 10) + 15 - 20) 

-- 5 * 2 = 10
--  10/10 = 1
--   1 + 15 = 16
-- 16 - 20 = -4

-- The Problem lies right here when there is a Variable and a constant together lua does not like that :/
local x = 10

print(5x + 5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print(5x + 5)` will trigger a syntax error; Lua does not allow implicit multiplication. The fix is trivial: Explicitly use the multiplication operator as in your first example: `print(5*x + 5)` works just fine.